# How would I go about making a hole in an HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table

[Table with spaces that I'm trying to get in the middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hovqf.jpg)

How do I get blank spaces in my table? I want to get it to look like the image above, but I want those empty spaces to be in the middle of the table rather than on the side.

```
<table style="width:100%" border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td> <!-- Added to show the kind of space I want in the table -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've looked up several different things but none of them seem to tell me exactly what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: You should explain in simple terms, referring to what we can actually see, what you want. “Hole” and “blank space” don’t do that. From the image, it seems that you just want some cells of a table to lack borders. Is it so? Which cells exactly should appear without borders?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to approach this using CSS instead of a border attribute on the parent table.  As is, you're setting a border on every cell in the table, and you want to pick whether or not you're going to show a border on a per-cell basis.

Basically, I'd:

```
<style type="text/css">

.borderedTable tr td {
border: solid 1px black;
}

.tableCellWithoutBorder {
  border-width: 0px;
}

</style>

<table cellpadding="10" class="borderedTable">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="tableCellWithoutBorder">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="tableCellWithoutBorder">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="tableCellWithoutBorder">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="tableCellWithoutBorder">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="tableCellWithoutBorder">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```